# can we know from which page the user visited this page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Is it possible in PHP to know which page a user came to a particular page from?

For example, the first page is `index.php` and the second page is `index2.php`.

Now the user goes to `index.php` from `index2.php` using a hyperlink which is on `index2.php`.

Now I want to store the link in a database, for the page the user came to `index.php` from, in this case `index2.php`.

Comment: session or referer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's on your own site you might as well use the session, `HTTP_REFERER` is prone to spam or very likely simply not set, you can't trust it.

Maybe do something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['last_page'])) {
   // first visit (landing)
} else {
   // not first page
}

// insert into db

// set tracking for next page
$_SESSION['last_page'] = [
  'page' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
  'time' => time() // know how long user was on the last page
];
```

Place it somewhere its hit on each page.

Comment: Sir I want to do this with two different websites? Plz help me out sir?

Comment: **Don't move the goal posts**, you didn't mention two different sites, then your only option is to use HTTP_REFERER (after checking domain origin) or if on same domain use cookies, then continue off as-above using session.

Comment: no worries, make sure you treat it as user input, I've seen many interesting things placed in the referer, from XSS to ads and ascii art..

Comment: Ok sir, well xss will not work I think so..only I want to store link values and no other action will associated with that.

Comment: Is there is any way to double check the referer

Comment: Yeah you could check the value is a valid domain name with `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`, and if you only want to track known ones just have an array you check against. after parsing out the domain with parse_url

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last page URL (which in this case will be the origin) using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable `$_SERVER`, it should tell you where the user came from.
You can use it like this in your index.php:

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to track sites that are from you, like `index.php` and `index2.php` then you should use a session and set the value on each page, its more precise than the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can easily be spoofed be the user.

Comment: Can please give me a demo program?